# NUMA: Win10 CPU utilization

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, numa

I develop a multithreaded cpu-intensive application. Until now this application has been tested on multicore (but single-cpu) systems like an i7-6800K and worked well under Linux and Windows. A newly observed phenomenon is that it does not run well on certain sever hardware: 2 x Xeon E5 2660 v3:

[image]

When 40 threads are active then cpu utilization drops to 5-10 %. This server has two physical CPUs and supports NUMA. The application has not been written with the NUMA-model in mind and thus we have certainly lots of memory accesses to non-local memory and that should be improved. But the question is: "Can low displayed cpu-utilization be caused by slow memory access?"

I believe this is the case but a colleque said that the cpu utilization would nevertheless stay at 100 %. This is important because if he is right then the trouble does not come from memory-misplacement. I don't know how Windows10 counts cpu utilization so I hope that somebody knows from practical experience with server hardware if the displayed cpu utilization drops in case of congested memory controllers.